# GridView Spacing Not Right

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I'm having trouble understanding what's wrong with my layout. I have a grid of 50x50px test images, and I'm trying to get them closer together so that they fit on the screen better, but I can't seem to make that happen, especially in the space between the rows. I'm wondering if there's something I can do to my XML to change fix that?
My XML is below and I'll attach a picture of what's happening in my emulator[emulator snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/drx2d.png)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridview"
        android:layout_width="500dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:verticalSpacing="0dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="0dp"
        android:numColumns="16"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="100dp"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >

        <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="50dp"
            android:width="150dp"
            android:text="Button 1"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="50dp"
            android:width="150dp"
            android:text="Button 2"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</GridLayout>
```

Comment: You should either use GridLayout for static configuration or use GridView for dynamic configuration. 
Note: GridView requires Adapter like RecyclerView
If I didn't get your question right plz clarify

Comment: @KiranBanmala I have an ImageAdapter class for adding and removing images from the grid, but at no point will there be more than 16 rows and 16 columns. I'm really just having trouble with tightening the space between the rows, as I can't seem to shrink the grid vertically without creating a scrollbar.